# Not sure if I understand anonymous procedures

Tags: scheme

```
(define (map2 liste1 liste2)
  (define (gj x y)
    (/ (+ x y) 2))
  (if (or (null? liste1) (null? liste2))
      '()
      (cons (gj (car liste1) (car liste2)) (map2 (cdr liste1) (cdr liste2)))))
```

Is procedure gj an anonymous procedure since it's within another procedure?

Comment: No, it's converted into a named lambda internally. The nesting hides the definition from any code that is not in the same lexical scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gj` is not anonymous since it has a name, which happens to be visible only within the scope of `map2`.

Examples of anonymous procedures would be:

```
> ((lambda (x) (* 2 x)) 10)
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
20
```

or

```
> (map (lambda (x) (+ x 1)) '(10 20 30))
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
'(11 21 31)
```

which have no name and cannot be referred to after the expression in which they are defined.

Note that

```
(define (gj x y)
  (/ (+ x y) 2))
```

is the same as

```
(define gj
  (lambda (x y)
    (/ (+ x y) 2)))
```

so here the procedure is bound to identifier `gj` and therefore it's no longer anonymous.

Comment: @YoungSande http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work. :)

Comment: @WillNess, sorry my bad!

Comment: @YoungSande Welcome to the Stack Overflow! :)